# Impala return null values after 'is not equal' condition

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to print the top 5 sports according to the duration.
I ran the below query:

```
with t1
AS
(
 select cast(duration as int),race,lap,sport
 from db.table1
 where exchange_code in ("tennis", "golf", "football")
 and table1_date = 20201010
 and duration is not null
 and race is not null 
 and lap is not null 
 and sport is not null
)
select sum(duration_int) ,race,lap,sport
from t1
group by race,lap,sport
order by sum(duration_int) desc
limit 5;
```

And the results are these:

```
 sum(duration_int) race   lap      sport
 [null]            first  second   golf
 408439363026         
 65886284          fourth third    football
 33687102          fifth  first    american-football    
 22642805          tenth  fifth    english-football
```

As you can see I have null values after the condition `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Impala [documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html) explains, `CAST()` does not return an error if it cannot cast the value, it returns `NULL`:

> If the expression value is of a type that cannot be converted to the target type, the result is NULL.

Hence, the condition `duration is not null` is not sufficient.  Instead:

```
cast(duration as int) is not null
```

I am not sure why `race`, `lap`, and `sport` would have `NULL` values.  I suspect the values may be the string `'[null]'`.

Comment: I tried your proposal and now I do not have null value in the first row. Although in second row it stills have this strange number with empty the other columns. Is this a total sum of the sums ?

Comment: @Thkas . .. Presumably that row consists of values where the three columns are not null, but have no visible values -- such as empty strings or all spaces.  You need to investigate the data to understand it better.

Comment: Used  !='' and everything ran smoothly. Are you suggesting any other way of implementation to find the top 5 sports on a specific day according their duration?

Comment: @Thkas . . . Based on what's in your question, your method is fine.